# Querying for today, within a week, and within a month

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm new. I'm writing an app for a laser tag place where we've got kids of many ages coming to shoot beams at each other. We're making a highscore screen that'll display the best scores of the day, of the week, and of the month. The idea is that people will feel proud being on the list, and there'll also be prizes once a month.

I'm getting stuck at the whole filtering by date thing.

I basically modified the classic guestbook example to the point where I can add scores and customer info, and sort them by score.

```
    Key guestbookKey = KeyFactory.createKey("Guestbook", guestbookName);
    String fornavn = req.getParameter("fornavn");
    Integer score = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("score"));
    String email = req.getParameter("email");
    String tlf = req.getParameter("tlf");
    Date date = new Date();
    Entity highscore = new Entity("Greeting", guestbookKey);
    highscore.setProperty("date", date);
    highscore.setProperty("fornavn", fornavn);
    highscore.setProperty("score", score);
    highscore.setProperty("email", email);
    highscore.setProperty("tlf", tlf);

    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    datastore.put(highscore);
```

And in the jsp there's a query that grabs the overall top 5.

```
Query query = new Query("Highscore", highscoreKey).addSort("score", Query.SortDirection.DESCENDING);
List<Entity> greetings = datastore.prepare(query).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(5));
```

And there's a form that sends the user input to the .java. Any tips as far as how I should set up the dates? Saving week # and month # and querying based on that? Seems cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, your "HighScore" kind is actually a "Score" kind that keeps track of all scores.

Instead of querying for the high score for the week/month, you're probably better off having a single HighScore entity (that's separate from normal "Score" entities) that you update whenever you enter a score.  Every time a new score is entered, check if the high score should be updated.

You never need a fancy query, you just need to fetch the high score entity.

Or you might want a separate high score entity for each month/week etc so you can keep track of the history.  In this case you may want to encode week or month into the entity key, so you can get the current week/month's HighScore easily.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possible approaches for a requirement like yours where you want to show highscores for a day, week, month, etc:

1, First option is to use your current model where you are storing date and score. Since app engine allows inequality filter only on 1 property, you need to apply an inequality filter on date and then find the n highest number of scores. But since the result will be sorted first for the property with inequality filter and then for any additional property, you cannot do a fetch for only the first n entries to find the top n because the top scores need not be in continuous order. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17480490/gae-datastore-query-with-filter-and-sort-using-objectify/17482104#17482104) to understand this better. So you will have to fetch all the scores for the date range and then do further sorting of the query result at your client to find the top n. This approach is ok if the total number of scores for a week or a month will not be too high compared to the value of n. If not, this is not a scalable option.

2, Second approach is to redesign your model such that sorting happens on scores so that for getting top n scores for a particular period, you need to fetch only the first n entries. This means the approach is suitable even if number of scores are very large. This then requires converting your date to be suitable for equality filtering like for each entry storing a month number, a week number and calendar year. Then for example if you want to find the top n scores in the 3rd month, then you can query for `month=3, sort by scores descending` and fetch the first n matching entries. Similarly you can query for a particular week using a week number.

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to another high-score SO question. I have copied/pasted my answer to it below. Approaching this solution using a database query may cause you to join the ranks of folks who complain about GAE. You will be using a custom index. Your query will likely average 10x miliseconds slower than needed per request. You will need to index thousands, perhaps millions of records. This costs you money -- perhaps lots of it both re: data storage (indices) and instances due to your high latency for what will likely be a highly-called handler function. Think different please. My copy/paste is not as specific to your setup, but it can be easily extended easily. I hope that it might prompt you to think about lower resource, lower cost alternative. As always...HTH. -stevep

Previous high score answer:
You may want to consider an alternate approach. This is a lot of index overhead which will cause your costs to be higher, the response time for the handler executing this function to operate an order of magnitude slower and you will have moments where the eventual consistency of index updates will affect maintenance of this data. If you have a busy site, you will surely not be happy with the latency and costs associated with this approach.

There are a number of alternate approaches. Your expected site transactions per second would affect which you choose. Here is a very simple alternative. Create an ndb entity with a TextProperty. Serialize the top scores entries using a string such as score_userid. Store them in the text field by joining them with a unique character. When a new score comes in, use get_by_id to retrieve this record (ndb automatically handles memcaching for you). Split it into an array. Split the last element of the array, and check against the new score. If it is less than the score, drop it, and append the new score_userid string to the array. Sort the array, join it, and put() the new TextProperty. If you want you could set up an end of the day cron to scan your scores for the day to check to see if your process was affected by the very small chance that two scores arrived at nearly the same time causing one to overwrite the other. HTH. -stevep

Previous SO high score answer link:

[GAE datastore query with filter and sort using objectify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17480490/gae-datastore-query-with-filter-and-sort-using-objectify/17492213#17492213)